# Click while loading elements (lazy loading ?)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, settimeout

We're creating an App using PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile.

We need to display a (very) long list of elements and they have to be displayed quickly. To do that, we first load 50 items, then the following 50, and so on. Doing this, the user can begin to work with the first items as soon as they are displayed.

The list is loaded using this kind of code:

```
function loadTheNext50Items() { 
  ...
  //loading stuff
  ...
  if (haveItemsNotLoaded) {
     setTimeout(loadTheNext50Items);
  }
}
```

This works great, except with some phones (Samsung S4 mini for example). With those phones, we can't interract with the loaded items until they are all loaded (clicks are not triggered for example).

Comment: when are you refreshing the list? anyway, it may be better to use an asynchronous function to prepare the list in a variable and refresh the list at the done function. example --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943207/how-to-make-progress-bar-update-every-time-an-applet-method-is-called-inside-a-l/25950226#25950226  - where it says (total: files.length) do (total: 1) to loop once. clear everything inside (}).progress(function(step) {) and do your work there by adding the new list items to a variarble eg (output += "<li>new row</li>";) and in the done function refresh the list.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the items are not just texted <li> tags. What takes time is inserting items in the DOM. So refreshing the all list is too long.

Comment: yes its a problem with lazy loading, refreshing the whole list.  Pagination is usually best